# how to read files from *.txt and import the data content to a png file that it create a diagram

Tags: python, png

I have *.txt files and now i want to take the data content and plot it in a Graph.
But the *.png have to be new create.

I have no clue how to create a png file and no clue about how to read the data content from a txt and put it in the png file that´s in the end a diagram.

any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "put it in" the PNG file? How should the PNG reflect the text?

Comment: Do you mean plot the data in a graph in png format? What have you tried so far?

Comment: yea thats what i mean. i have tried nothing because i have totaly no clue how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the packages `numpy` and `matplotlib`

```
import nunmpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data=np.loadtxt("YourFileName.txt", dtype="YourDataType", delimiter=",")
plt.plot(data)
plt.show()    #if you want to see the plot
plt.savefig("PngFile.png")
```

Done.

Comment: perfect, thats what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

If you need to plot a graph like diagram from your data, consider using [graphviz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphviz).

If you have an ascii art diagram that you want to convert into a `.png`, consider using [ditaa](http://ditaa.sourceforge.net/).

If you want to create an arbitrary png using some data, consider using [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/).

Comment: I want to plot from txt to png but i need to use python

Comment: You've not mentioned what you have in your `.txt` file. As I mentioned, the tool and method depends on what and how you want to plot your data. A screenshot is different from a histogram.